# Bigram network graph using tidy text mining [r | ggraph | igraph]

Tags: r, data-visualization, igraph, text-mining, ggraph

**It is fixed now after following the comments.**

I'm following the tutorial given here - https://www.tidytextmining.com/ngrams.html.

What I want to do is create a bigram network graph of review text present in a CSV file.

Here is the link to the dataset - https://app.box.com/s/y6nsmji4ir7nbggmbncnhf21xla96nml.

Here is the code:

```
library(dplyr)
library(tidyr)
library(tidytext)
library(ggplot2)
library(igraph)
library(ggraph)
library(stringr)

kjv <- read.csv(file.choose())

count_bigrams <- function(dataset) {
  dataset %>%
    unnest_tokens(bigram, commentText, token = "ngrams", n = 2) %>%
    separate(bigram, c("word1", "word2"), sep = " ") %>%
    filter(!word1 %in% stop_words$word,
           !word2 %in% stop_words$word) %>%
    count(word1, word2, sort = TRUE)
}

visualize_bigrams <- function(bigrams) {
  set.seed(2016)
  a <- grid::arrow(type = "closed", length = unit(.15, "inches"))

  bigrams %>%
    graph_from_data_frame() %>%
    ggraph(layout = "fr") +
    geom_edge_link(aes(edge_alpha = n), show.legend = FALSE, arrow = a) +
    geom_node_point(color = "lightblue", size = 5) +
    geom_node_text(aes(label = name), vjust = 1, hjust = 1) +
    theme_void()
}

kjv_bigrams <- kjv %>% 
  count_bigrams()
```

Here I'm getting the following error:
`Error in summarise_impl(.data, dots) : 
  Evaluation error: argument`...`should be a character vector (or an object coercible to).`

This is how the dataset looks like:

[image]

Thanks for the read!

Comment: Your `count_bigrams` function is expecting a dataframe as input but you are only passing it a single column.

Comment: Thanks. I updated the code, now getting another error.

Comment: I guess the headings or structure of `kjv` do not match what your function is expecting.  It is hard to say more without seeing an example of your data.  Try running the code in the function line by line to see where it is failing.

Comment: Try using `read_csv` rather than `read.csv` to read in your data - the problem might just be that it is converting the text to factors.

Comment: Tried that as well. Same issue.

Comment: Some of your lines have commas in the text.  Perhaps try `read_tsv()` (you will need the `readr` package loaded for these).

Comment: Found it - the second line of your function is using the wrong column name - you need `unnest_tokens(bigram, commentText, token = "ngrams", n = 2)` (this was after using `read_csv` to read the data)

Comment: How silly of me! Thanks -- it is solved now.